# Does this code return false only if the last function call is false, or if any of them are?

Tags: c#

I came across this legacy code:

```
public static bool RemoveTempFiles()
{
    bool RetVal = true;

    RetVal &= RemoveFile(@"\", "*.csv");
    RetVal &= RemoveFile(@"\", "*.xml");
    RetVal &= RemoveFile(@"\", "*.txt");
    RetVal &= RemoveFile(@"\", "*.tmp");

    RetVal &= RemoveFile(GetDataPath(), "*.csv");
    RetVal &= RemoveFile(GetDataPath(), "*.xml");
    RetVal &= RemoveFile(GetDataPath(), "*.txt");
    RetVal &= RemoveFile(GetDataPath(), "*.tmp");

    return RetVal;
}
```

...and I'm not familiar with the "&=" operator.

RemoveFile() deletes all files with the extension provided, and returns true unless an exception is encountered.

Since I don't know "&=" I don't know whether any failure causes RemoveTempFiles() to return false or if it would only return false if the last one (for *.tmp files) failed (which is how I would expect the code to work at first glance, but which makes no sense).

Comment: Read [&= operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: Why is that code considered "legacy"?

Comment: It really is that simple: In the Visual Studio editor, move the text caret onto "&=" and hit that sexy F1 key. Or just click on the link given by Vache...

Comment: @Greg: Because it is: it is years old, and the coder of it has absquatulated.

Comment: Perhaps worth of note is that `&` works like a logical AND when used with *bool* operands. However, contrary to `&&`, the `&` operator does not short-circuit.

Comment: In addition to reading the link given by Vache, you can learn about the `&=` operator for yourself with minimal code and a debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code will return false if **any** of the called functions returns false.

Each line is like writing

```
retVal = retVal & RemoveFiles; // Or &&!
```

Clearly this will return false if `RemoveFiles` returns false, and then will always return false after that.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Regarding your code comment: Do not use `&&` in this case! `&&` does short-circuit and thus would prevent invocation of *RemoveFiles* if a prior invocation of *RemoveFiles* did set *retVal* to `false`.

Comment: @elgonzo Excellent point! I was including it because & does a logical AND operation on bool, but this is a very good "gotcha". Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

This code returns false if even just one of the `RemoveFile` returns false.

As stated in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx , it's the same as assigning to the first variable (`x`) the result of the AND with the second variable (`y`) so it's like`x= (x&y)`

Answer (score 2):

`RetVal &= x` is simply shorthand for `RetVal = RetVal & x`. So the result will be true only if all the values are true (and false if any of them is false)

If you use `RetVal |= x`, then the result will be true if any value is true (and false if all of them are false).